# How to find out in which div the last and current image has been placed ( draggable, jQuery UI )

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I am trying to make my own version of Rapid Sorting from the BrainWars game with javascript/jQuery/jQuery UI (currently available on Android and iOS ).

The game:
images appear one after another.
for example: A square symbol shows up , you have to drag it to the left or right side. ( one div container left and one the right ).
Lets say you throw it in the left container.

if the next image that appears is also a square symbol you have to throw it in the same container as you threw the last same image in.

My problem(s):

- how to find out in which the last image was in, and how to check if the player has throwed the image in the same container as the last one ( IF last and current image matched ).
- If the above function case is true, player score should increase with 10 (integer) points.

See example of the game:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_LXGjIbuSY

So far I have this :  http://lastdimension.nl/rapidsorting/

( click rocket to start game )

( images of random animals will appear)

( you can drag them and throw them on the left - or the right side of screen, indicated with borders for test purposes )

I would love to know / see a fiddle for my case on how to accomplish the check for current and last image and to do a score increment if its correct.

my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <audio id="bubblePlay" src="audio/bubble.mp3"></audio>
  <audio preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/bubble.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
  </audio>


  <audio id="correctPlay" src="audio/correct.mp3"></audio>
  <audio preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/correct.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
  </audio>

  <audio preload="auto" loop autplay>
    <source src="audio/background.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
  </audio>
  <audio loop id="backgroundPlay" src="audio/background.mp3"></audio>

  <script>
    function bubblePlay() {
      var audio = document.getElementById("bubblePlay");
      audio.play();
    };

    function backgroundPlay() {
      var audio = document.getElementById("backgroundPlay");
      audio.play();
    };

    function correctPlay() {
      var audio = document.getElementById("correctPlay");
      audio.play();
    };
  </script>

</head>

<body>


  <center>



</body>

</html>
<img id="bird" src="gif/bird.gif">
<div id="dvSource">
  <img src="img/kat/kat_oranje.png" id="img1">
  <img src="img/zeehond/zeehond_blauw.png" id="img2">
  <img src="img/aap/aap_roze.png" id="img3">
  <img src="img/aap/aap_roze.png" id="img4">
  <img src="img/leeuw/leeuw_groen.png" id="img5">
  <img src="img/olifant/olifant_oranje.png" id="img6">
</div>


<div id="dvDest">
  <!-- LEFT CONTAINER -->
</div>

<div id="dvDest2">
  <!-- RIGHT CONTAINER -->
</div>




</center>

<div id="start_scherm">
  <input type="image" width="350px" id="start_button" src="gif/rocket/play2.gif" title="START">


  </br>
  </br>
</div>

<div id="animated-area"></div>
```

My javascript:

```js
/*   
if (last image && current image are the same AND put in same container){
 score =0;
 score = score+10;
 document.getElementById('scoreboard').innerHTML = score;
}
*/

// drag function
$(function() {
  var score = "";
  $("#dvSource img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: false,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {

      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
      var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
      if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
        //if dropped in container
        correctPlay()
      } else {
        // if not dropped in container
      }
    }
  });


  // container left
  $("#dvDest").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
        $("#dvDest").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
      $("img1").dropped
    }
  });


  // container right
  $("#dvDest2").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($("#dvDest2 img").length == 0) {
        $("#dvDest2").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#dvDest2").append(ui.draggable);
      console.log("dropped in right");
    }
  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dvSource, #dvDest, #dvDest2").hide();
  $("#bird").show();
  $('#bird').animate({
    right: '100%'
  }, 4500, 'swing');
  $('#start_button').hover(function() {
    $("#start_button").addClass('transition');

  }, function() {
    $("#start_button").removeClass('transition');
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start_button').mouseover(function() {
    bubblePlay()
    $('#start_button').attr('src', 'gif/rocket/play2.gif');
  })
  $('#start_button').mouseout(function() {
    $('#start_button').attr('src', 'gif/rocket/play2.gif');
  });

  $('#start_button').click(function() {
    $('#start_scherm').fadeOut(1500);
    $("#dvSource, #dvDest, #dvDest2").show();

    setTimeout(function() {


      // show images one after another with timeout
      $(document).ready(function() {
        backgroundPlay()

        var one = setTimeout(function() {
          $('#img1').show(350).animate({
            top: '190%'
          }, 2500, 'linear'); //.hide(350);
        }, 1500)


        var two = setTimeout(function() {
          $('#img2').show(350).animate({
            top: '190%'
          }, 2500, 'linear'); //.hide(350); 
        }, 4500)


        var three = setTimeout(function() {
          $('#img3').show(350).animate({
            top: '190%'
          }, 2500, 'linear'); //.hide(350);
        }, 7500)


        var four = setTimeout(function() {
          $('#img4').show(350).animate({
            top: '190%'
          }, 2500, 'linear'); //.hide(350); 
        }, 10500)

      });

    }, 3000);
  })
});
```

Comment: Maybe I should specify what I want as I still see no response to my question:

I need:
- A way to check in which div ( left or right ) , the current image has been dropped
+ - a way to check if the last shown image was the same as current image AND if its dropped in the same container, if true, score +10.

I am far from being experienced with jQuery UI so i'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be creating kind of a history stack for activities happening in your game. The array that will contain all the state changes one by one so that you can always check what action was back.
Say following way:

```
//declaring
var history = [];

//in each droppable containters
$("#dvDest2").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
  //other code
  console.log("dropped in right");
  history.push({'type': 'drop', 'destination': 'dvDest2', item: ui.draggable.prop('id')});
  }
});
```

so now after each drop you can see history growing by one, and can check what was 1 step back:

```
var previousStep = history[history.length-1];
//previousStep - should be then {'type': 'drop', 'destination': 'dvDest2', item: 'img1'}
```

then you can do comparing previous step with current

```
if(previousStep.destination == WHATEVER) { /*allow on not allow smth */}
//or
if(previousStep.item != WHATEVER) { /*allow on not allow smth */}
```

Comment: var history = [];

//in each droppable containters
$("#dvDest2").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
  //other code
  console.log("dropped in right");
  history.push({'type': 'drop', 'destination': 'dvDest2', item: ui.draggable.prop('id')});
  }
});

Should that be a new function or replace it with my current? I'm not very familiar with the jQueryUI and have used some snippets from other sources and I'm not sure what the steps in the above code does.
I am also not sure where the 'item' and 'destination' from previousSteps should represent.

Comment: 1) this - var history = []; should be added on top; 2) this - history.push({'type': 'drop', 'destination': 'dvDest2', item: ui.draggable.prop('id')}); should be added into existing code; 3) this - var previousStep = history[history.length-1]; should be used where you want to have the cheking

Comment: I've tried what you said, but keep getting 'undefined' when I try to output it with console.log. See my updated JS file after your comments: https://jsfiddle.net/LhLyh6xr/5/ and see lastdimension.nl/rapidsorting to see the console.log ( after you've pressed rocket gif to start the game )

Comment: In the way game works currently now I first get all images falling down one after another to the bottom of the page and then I can drag them to one of the containers - is that a desired behaviour? Or I must catch them while they fall? >_<

Comment: Lol... Yes, you have to catch the silly animals..part of my silly game ( school project ) and you dont have to wait till they fall all under... you can grab them as soon as they appear and throw them in one of the containers. I'm almost done except this check function... Only if I could make it work... so I can add scoreboard feature and other stuff.